# Proper structure syntax for Delphi/Pascal if then begin end and ;

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

It has been around 20 years since I last had to write in Pascal. I can't seem to use the structure elements of the language correctly where I am nesting `if then` blocks using `begin` and `end`. For example this gets me an Compiler Error *"Identifier Expected"*.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Log('Initialize Wizard');
  if IsAdminLoggedOn then begin
    SetupUserGroup();
    SomeOtherProcedure();
  else begin (*Identifier Expected*)
    Log('User is not an administrator.');
    msgbox('The current user is not administrator.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end  
  end;
end;
```

Of course if I remove the `if then` block and the `begin end` blocks associated with them then everything is OK.

Sometimes I get it this kind of syntax right and it works out OK, but the problems become exasperated when nesting the `if then else` blocks.

Solving the problem is not enough here. I want to have a better understanding how to use these blocks. I am clearly missing a concept. Something from C++ or C# is probably creeping in from another part of my mind and messing up my understanding. I have read a few articles about it, and well I think I understand it and then I don't.

Comment: I had to learn this terrible language in order to write Inno Setup scripts. My God.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to match every `begin` with an `end` at the same level, like

```pascal
if Condition then
begin
  DoSomething;
end
else
begin
  DoADifferentThing;
end;
```

You can shorten the number of lines used without affecting the placement, if you prefer. (The above might be easier when you're first getting used to the syntax, though.)

```pascal
if Condition then begin
  DoSomething
end else begin
  DoADifferentThing;
end;
```

If you're executing a single statement, the `begin..end` are optional. Note that the first condition does not contain a terminating `;`, as you're not yet ending the statement:

```pascal
if Condition then
  DoSomething
else
  DoADifferentThing;
```

The semicolon is optional at the last statement in a block (although I typically include it even when it's optional, to avoid future issues when you add a line and forget to update the preceding line at the same time).

```pascal
if Condition then
begin
  DoSomething;            // Semicolon required here
  DoSomethingElse;        // Semicolon optional here
end;                      // Semicolon required here unless the
                          // next line is another 'end'.
```

You can combine single and multiple statement blocks as well:

```pascal
if Condition then
begin
  DoSomething;
  DoSomethingElse;
end
else
  DoADifferentThing;

if Condition then
  DoSomething
else
begin
  DoADifferentThing;
  DoAnotherDifferentThing;
end;
```

The correct use for your code would be:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Log('Initialize Wizard');
  if IsAdminLoggedOn then 
  begin
    SetupUserGroup();
    SomeOtherProcedure();
  end 
  else 
  begin 
    Log('User is not an administrator.');
    msgbox('The current user is not administrator.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Somehow I had the mistaken impression that the else block ended a begin block.... I have no idea where I got that crazy idea from. Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @amalgamate: If you're not using `begin`, you don't need `end`. See my third code sample above.

Comment: Thanks vary much, I think that fixes my brain to a correct state on the subject.