# “END” expected but “IF” found. Stalked with some problem in turbo pascal code

Tags: pascal, turbo-pascal

```
program calc;
   var a,b,c,d:real; 
Begin
   write('a=');readln(a);
   write('b=');readln(b);
   write('c=');readln(c);
   if a = 0 then
      if b = 0 then
         if c = 0 then
            writeln('equation undetermined,S=R')
         else
            begin
               d := b * b - 4 * a * c; <<<< missed ';'?
               if (d >= 0) then
                  begin
                     writeln('x1=',(-b-sqrt(d))/(2* a):6:2 ); <<< missed ')' ?
                     writeln('x2=',(-b+sqrt(d))/(2* a):6:2 ); <<< missed ')' ?
                  end;
               else 
                  writeln ('Equation has no real solutions');
            end;
            readln;
End.
```

Comment: Try formatting and indenting the program.

Comment: Apart from anything else you need a semicolon after `d:=b*b-4*a*c` and you should remove the one immediately before `else writeln ...`

Comment: The problem no longer appears. I can run the program, but when I’m introducing 3 numbers, like a=2; b=3; c=4, nothing happens

Comment: That can be, because your sequence of if a = 0 then if b = 0 then if c = 0 then. That will result in no processing when you enter a value different of 0 ...

Comment: I assume, you would like to reduce your 3 ifs to: if (a = 0) or (b = 0) or (c=0) then writeln .... else  begin .. end..... see my answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper structure syntax for Pascal if then begin end and ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221394/proper-structure-syntax-for-pascal-if-then-begin-end-and)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
Program Calc;
   var a,b,c,d: Real; 

Begin
   Write('a='); ReadLn(a);
   Write('b='); ReadLn(b);
   Write('c='); ReadLn(c);

   if (a = 0) or (b = 0) or (c = 0) then
      WriteLn('equation undetermined,S=R')
   else
      Begin
         d := b * b - 4 * a * c;
         if (d >= 0) then
            Begin
               WriteLn('x1=', (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a):6:2 );
               WriteLn('x2=', (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a):6:2 );
            end;
         else 
            WriteLn('Equation has no real solutions');
      end;

   ReadLn;
End.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ...
then if ...
     then ...
     else ...
```

might also compile as

```
if ...
then if ...
     then ...
else ...
```

instead use

```
if ...
then begin
     if ...
     then ...
end
else ...
```

Comment: Your code formatting method is even worse than the OPs. Not sure how this helps.