# (13,3) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found

Tags: freepascal

```
Program prueba1;
uses Estructu;
Var Pila1:Pila; Fila1,Completa:Fila;
Begin
    Inicfila (Completa);
    readpila(Pila1);
    readfila(Fila1);
    While (not pilavacia(Pila1) and not filavacia(Fila1)) do
    begin
        if (tope(Pila1) > primero(Fila1)) then
        begin
            agregar(Completa, desapilar(Pila1))
        else
            if (tope(Pila1) < primero(Fila1)) then
            begin
                agregar(Completa, extraer(Fila1))
            else
                if (tope(Pila1) = primero(Fila1)) then
                begin
                    agregar(Completa, desapilar(Pila1));
                    agregar(Completa, extraer(Fila1))
                end
            end
        end
    end
    write('El resultado final de Completa es');
    Writefila(Completa);
End.
```

The purpose of the program would be to organise in Completa all the variables from Pila1 and Fila1 in order from first to last.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate the help

Comment: You may find it helpful to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28221465/62576) I posted that provides a tutorial on the proper use of `begin` and `end` in Pascal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `if ... then ... else` and `begin ... end` correctly.

There is the concept of a **block**, which is started with `begin` and ended with `end`. Anywhere where a single **statement** is expected, you can put a **block** instead. This is also the case for `if <condition> then <statement> else <statement>;`.

So, this code is valid:

```pascal
if something() then
  stuff
else
  stuff;
```

...as is this:

```pascal
if something() then
  begin
    stuff;
    moreStuff;
  end
else
  begin
    otherStuff;
    moreOtherStuff;
  end;
```

However, this (which you are using) is not:

```pascal
if something() then
  begin
    stuff // I guess here you omitted the semicolon because you correctly remembered
          // that there shouldn't be a semicolon before `else`, but...
else // WRONG, this is in the middle of the block!
    otherStuff;
  end;
```

To see why, let's fix the indention to match the logical interpretation of this code:

```pascal
if something() then
  begin
    stuff
    else // ????????
    otherStuff;
  end;
```

You get an error since `begin ... else ... end` is not a valid construct. Since there is a `begin` but then no `end` before the `else`, your `else` is in the middle of the `then` block which makes no sense.

Make sure to `end` your block before starting the `else` part, and then `begin` a new block.

Comment: My thanks though now I'm having problems with the write and writefila lines

Comment: I think you are missing the `;` after the condition ended. So at the `end` that concludes the `if` or `while`, you need a `;` (**not** before the `else` though).

Comment: it would be also nice to omit ;'s after the last statements in begin end. Thin about it as begin and end are brackets and you are using ; to separate elements in brackets. You do not need ; after the last element in begin end. Many compilers will tolerate it or even insert empty statement after last ;